# Not able to get click event in view pager's Fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I created a View pager and set the Transformer

```
 mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pagerContainer);
    pager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    pager.setPageTransformer(true, new CubeOutTransformer());
```

And adapter consists of fragment, I'm not able to get a click event on the fragment's child. However on removing pager.setPageTransformer (true, new CubeOutTransformer(); it works fine.

So, is there any way I can get the click event and keep the transform animation?

Comment: can you show how you are doing this.?

Comment: inside the fragments's onCreateView method   tvAddMOney.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.d(TAG,"clicked " +currentPos);
                    }
                });

Comment: is there any error you got..?

Comment: no, I'm not getting any log on clicking the view, but if i remove the pager.setPageTransformer(true, new CubeOutTransformer()); it works fine

Comment: please show your code of fragment class where you getting it.

Comment: TextView tvAddMOney = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvAddMOney);

Comment: and how you initialize rootview ?

Comment: yes , View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);